# java default access modifiers

Tags: java, default, public

I am a complete beginner in java, so please forgive me if this question is not up to the standard of this website:

```
class person{
    String name;
    int age;
}
class teacher extends person{
  person s1=new person();
  teacher t1=new teacher();
  t1.age=56;
}
```

Here I am trying to access the variable age and name of class to assign them values person, which happens to be the super class of  person. But the compiler is giving error. I even tried to make the name variable and age variable as public. But the compiler is still reporting an error. I want to know the reason why I can't access superclass variable in subclass directly and assign values to them.

Comment: What error do you get? You're using code out of a method (```t1.age=56;```).

Comment: OK, even a beginner should be able to use the spacebar appropriately...

Comment: When the compiler gives an error, always include it in your question.

Comment: An unrelated (but important) thing to know is that in Java, class names should begin with an uppercase letter, while field, variable and method names with a lowercase one. This isn't a rule enforced by the compiler but a naming convention used by almost every Java developer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to write arbitrary code directly within a class body. The closest thing to what you have written is

```
class teacher extends person{
  person s1=new person();
  teacher t1=new teacher();
  {
    t1.age=56;
  }
}
```

This is called the *instance initializer* block.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not a good idea to access variables directly.  Consider using something like the code below.

**Test driver**

```
package com.example.input;

public class TestPeople {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Person s1 = new Person();
            s1.setName("student 1").setAge(19);
            Teacher t1 = new Teacher("Dr. Fun",0);
            t1.setAge(56);

            System.out.println("Student " + s1.getName() + ", " + s1.getAge());
            System.out.println("Teacher  " + t1.getName() + ", " + t1.getAge());
        }

    }
```

**Class Person**

```
package com.example.input;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person() {};
    public Person(String aName, int anAge) {
        setName(aName).setAge(anAge);
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}

    public Person setName(String aName) { name = aName; return this;}
    public Person setAge(int anAge) { age = anAge; return this;}

}
```

**Class Teacher**

```
package com.example.input;

public class Teacher extends Person {

    public Teacher() {
        super();
    }
    public Teacher(String aName, int anAge) {
        super(aName, anAge);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are making an assignment of variable of external class in existing class body which is not legal.Make the assignment in a method or constructor or in a anonymous block.

```
class person{
    String name;
    int age;
}
class teacher extends person{
    person s1=new person();
    teacher t1=new teacher();
    // t1.age=56; Error here
    public teacher()
    {
         t1.age=56;
    }
    //or method
    public void setAge()
    {
         t1.age=56;
    }
}
```

do whatever suits your program and you.